# angular material mat-radio-button default checked not working after adding name on mat-radio-group

Tags: angular, forms, angular-material, angular5, radio-group

In an Angular 5 app with angular material 5.2.5, when using this code the radio button default checked is working but there is an error in console

Code :

```
<mat-radio-group [(ngModel)]="collection">
  <mat-radio-button class="collectionRadioButton" 
   *ngFor="let coll of collections" 
   [value]="coll.endPoint" 
   [checked]="coll.isDefault" 
   (change)="clearResults()">
  {{coll.label}}
  </mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

Error in Chrome console :

```
ERROR Error: If ngModel is used within a form tag, either the name attribute must be set or the form control must be defined as 'standalone' in ngModelOptions.

Example 1: <input [(ngModel)]="person.firstName" name="first">   
Example 2: <input [(ngModel)]="person.firstName" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
at Function.TemplateDrivenErrors.missingNameException (forms.js:5891)
at NgModel._checkName (forms.js:6244)
at NgModel._checkForErrors (forms.js:6217)
at NgModel.ngOnChanges (forms.js:6099)
at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:12407)
at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:13935)
at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:13878)
at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:14771)
at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:14712)
```

But when adding a name to mat-radio-group

```
<mat-radio-group [(ngModel)]="collection" [name]="'aList'">
```

then the radio button list is still correctly generated but the default checked is no longer working ...

Comment: Full code? Looks like your code is nested in a `<form>`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will need the name="your_name" near [(ngModel)], then the checked property will not work but you can do like this.

```
<form>  
 <mat-radio-group [(ngModel)]="radioOptions" name="radioButtons">
    <mat-radio-button [value]="'TEST1'">TEST1</mat-radio-button>
    <mat-radio-button [value]="'TEST2'">TEST2</mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group> </form>

  import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
  export class ConfigurazioneComponent implements OnInit {
     radioOptions: string = 'TEST1'; 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If im not mistaken, you can't use `[name]="''"` but `name=""`

```
name="{{aList}}" // this should work just fine if that aList was variable else
name="aList" // if its a string
```

Comment: Already tryed, it doesn't work either with name="{{aList}}" or name="aList"

Answer (score 0):

To work wihout name and just with object, then collection should be an instance of collections to works and add [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" attribute.

Example in your code:
Component :

```
  this.collection = this.collections.find(x => x.isDefault)
```

Template:

```
<mat-radio-group [(ngModel)]="collection">
    <mat-radio-button class="collectionRadioButton" 
                      *ngFor="let coll of collections" 
                      [value]="coll" 
                      (change)="clearResults()"
                      [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" >
       {{coll.label}}
    </mat-radio-button>
  </mat-radio-group>
```